# XCode 12.4 Error : Multiple commands produce

Tags: xcode, react-native, error-handling

There are 16 errors like below. All of the files are `.ttf`, and the files are not duplicated in `Copy Bundle Resources`

> Multiple commands produce '/Users/actbase/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/showket-drypehsfryqmshafhuwrxhokldtc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/showket.app/Zocial.ttf':
>
> 1. Target 'showket' (project 'showket') has copy command from
>    '/Users/actbase/project/showket-app/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Zocial.ttf'
>    to
>    '/Users/actbase/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/showket-drypehsfryqmshafhuwrxhokldtc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/showket.app/Zocial.ttf'
> 2. That command depends on command in Target 'showket' (project
>    'showket'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

Could you help me out?